# Nodejs multi part http download

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, download, multipart

At the web app I'd developing there is an option for users to download large files via browser. The files could be stored at different remote storages, for example Amazon S3. If the file download took more than a few minutes it would be handy to track it's progress at the server side for various reasons.

So the web app and node.js API are located at one place and the file could be located anywhere. What I was thinking is to proxy the file download through node.js. So it looks like --> user clicks the file download button at web app --> node asks S3 for a file and streams it to the user and updates the DB to track the progress as the file size and data sent are known.

What I'd like to know:

1. Is that reasonable in terms of performance ? Will hundreds of parallel download kill the average server or not ?
2. How to handle the multi part download with node ?
3. Are there better solutions to this problem ?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

*solution 1*: The best way would be to directly download the files from your server. This enable you to watch the progression, to have a total control and to add some functionnality when you want. The performance of your downloading depand on **your** server.

*solution 2*: If you don't want to store the files or you don't want to serve the file you can provide a link `<a href="link_to_the_remote_file">link</a>` which point to the remote server's file. For your server, there is no impact, that's good. Still, you can't watch the progress.

So, either your server manages the downloads, either a remote server. Both have pros and cons.
But in the case of your server, you will need to parse the file. You can use a module, but if you want to make it by yourself (witch is better), take a look at the native `fs` and `stream` modules and the `http protocol`.
In the other case, you don't need, you do nothing.

Your solution is: a remote server serves files to your server which serves to the client.
**I've never tested for the moment**, but it seems that you do 2 things: **download** and **upload**. It is better the solutions above which either download or upload.